# Vue.js cannot style anchor

Tags: css

I'm trying to style my anchor but it doesn't work. Can someone explain what's wrong with my code?

```html
<a href="#" class="sasadada">PIC</a>
```

And this is for my CSS

```css
<style>
sasadada {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
sasadada:active {
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: you forget to add `.` dot class selector before class name in css

Comment: Not adding the `.` dot class selector means you are now styling a custom tag in HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because there is no "." on css selectors.

```css
<style>
.sasadada{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.sasadada:active {
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style scoped>
.sasadada{
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:500px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
.sasadada:active {
     color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: @Calculuswhiz https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html  ..its one of best practise in vue for scope styles